# Download a file from Azure DevOps pipeline and publish it's contents to ADO wiki page using PowerShell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-wiki

I have been trying to download a file from Azure DevOps pipeline and publish it's contents to ADO wiki page using PowerShell. But I couldn't figure out a way to do so.

It is a .csv file which is being generated by my PS script in the Azure DevOps Classic pipeline that contains some of user's details and will be located in the C:\Users.csv MS Hosted Agent, which I want to download it manually to my local machine and the same csv file has be published to ADO Wiki page.

I used 'Publish Pipeline Artifact' Task to publish the .csv file and to download the artifact I used 'Download Pipeline Artifact' but no way to get this .csv file to my local machine.

Kindly suggest/help me the find the right approach to get this done.

Comment: The REST API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1